# Unable to Create Power Apps Nested Galleries From Multiple Lists

Tags: sharepoint-online, powerapp

I have two SharePoint lists that are linked together through a lookup field. I am trying to visualize these two lists in a single PowerApps visual using a Nested Galleries approach, where Gallery 1 will contain the Domains, and then Gallery 2 will be nested and contain the specific Sub-Domains underneath their respective parent Domain.

I can get the data for both Domain list and Sub-Domain list to populate in the respective galleries; however, I am unable to properly filter the Sub-Domain gallery so it only displays the items that fall under the parent Domain. What I need is to create a filter in the Gallery2 Items which looks approximately something like this `Gallery2 Items = Filter(SubDomainDataSource, Gallery1DomainItem = ThisItem.ParentDomainLookupField)`

There are two problems that I am encountering which prevent me from filtering appropriately:

1. I don't know how to access the parent object in the nested gallery in order to compare against the current Domain item that acts as the parent
2. I don't have access to the lookup field in the SubDomain data source, it simply does not appear in Power Apps as an available field to reference. All other fields are available except for the lookup field, so even if I could access the parent object from #1 I cannot get access to the necessary key value in the child gallery in order to tie the data together.

Example of Lists:

List 1:

| Domain |
| --- |
| Dom1 |
| Dom2 |
| Dom3 |

List 2:

| Sub-Domain | Parent Domain (lookup field to List 1) |
| --- | --- |
| SubDomA | Dom1 |
| SubDomB | Dom1 |
| SubDomC | Dom2 |
| SubDomD | Dom2 |

Answer (score 0):

In the second Gallery → Items Property → Set the formula like this :

```
Filter(Subdomains,ParentDomain.Value=Gallery1.Selected.Domain)
```

Here is my try :

- Domains List :

[image]

- Subdomains List

[image]

And here is the result :

https://gfycat.com/acrobaticshallowblacklab